# Implicit function theorem with multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> Let $f_{1}, f_{2}: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functions
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & f_{1}(x, y, t):=2 x^{4}+y-t, \\
> & f_{2}(x, y, t):=x^{2}+2 y^{3}+t^{2} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>
> Show there exists a neighborhood $W$ of $1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and a unique $C^{1}$ function $g=\left(g_{1}, g_{2}\right): W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $$g(1)=(1,-1)$$ and $$f_{i}\left(g_{1}(t), g_{2}(t), t\right)=0$$ for $i=1,2$ and $t \in W$.

**My attempt:**
The implicit function theorem states that if $f$ is $C^{1}$ and $f(x_{0},y_{0}) = 0$ and the $m \times m \text{ matrix } \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(x_{0},y_{0})$ is invertible, then there exists a open neighborhood $W$ in $x_{0}$ and a unique $C^{1}$-image.

So both $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ is clearly $C^{1}$ and $f(1,-1,1) = 0$
for both $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$
Now I need to show that the $m \times m \text{ matrix }$ is invertible by showing the determinant of $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(-1,1) \neq 0$.
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
8x^{3} & 1 & -1 \\
2x & 6y^{2} & 2t 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
6y^{2} & 2t 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So the determinant is $-6y^{2}-2t$. Plugging in $(-1,1)$ gives $-8 \neq 0$. So we can use the implicit function theorem.

I am wondering if this is correct. Because I don't understand the part $g(1)=(1,-1)$, and I haven't done anything with this information.

Comment: The $x$ and $y$ of the general theorem are here respectively our $t$ and $(x,y).$  (Note that here they are in reversed order inside $f.$) So, the $2\times2$ matrix which you need to be invertible is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,y)}=\begin{pmatrix}
8x^{3} & 1\\
2x & 6y^{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$ The part $g(1)=(1,-1)$ has been used when checking that $f(1,-1,1)=0.$  The $x_0$ and $y_0$ of the general theorem are here respectively $1$ and $(1,-1).$

Comment: Please call the functions $f$ and $g$, The notation $f_1$ is commonly used for the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and will lead to confusion, even worse when you take partial derivatives of your two functions.